# Making a presence/absence matrix (y axis is file names, x axis is reads in file)

Tags: python, bash, bioinformatics, biopython

I have multiple files (filenames) with multiple sequence reads (Each has a readname that starts with >) in them:

Filename1

```
>Readname1

>Readname2
```

Filename2

```
>Readname1

>Readname3
```

Given a dictionary that contains all possible readnames like this:

```
g={}

g['Readname1']=[]

g['Readname2']=[]

g['Readname3']=[]
```

How could I write code that would iterate each file and generate the following matrix:

```
          Filename1 Filename2

Readname1  1        1

Readname2  1        0

Readname3  0        1
```

The code should scan the contents of each file in the directory. Ideally I could read the dictionary from an input file, rather than hard-coded, so I can generate matrices for different dictionaries. The content of each read (e.g. its gene sequence) is not relevant, just whether the readname is present or absent in that file.

I am just learning python, so a colleague shared their code to get me started. Here they were creating a presence/absence matrix of their dictionary (Readnames) in a single specified file (files.txt). I would like to input the dictionary from a second file (so that it's not static in the code) and to iterate over multiple files.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import os
dir_path="" #directory path
files=os.listdir(path=dir_path)
with open(dir_path+'files.txt') as f:
    files=f.readlines()
files=[x.strip() for x in files]
enter code here

g={}  
g['Readname1']=[]
g['Readname2']=[]
g['Readname3']=[]

for i in files:
    a = list(SeqIO.parse(dir_path + i, 'fasta')) 
    for j in a:
        g[j.id].append(i) 
print('generating counts...')
counts={} 
for i in g.keys():
   counts[i]=[] 

for i in files: 
    for j in g: 
        if i in g[j]: 
            counts[j].append(1)
        else:
            counts[j].append(0)

print('writing out...')
outfile=open(dir_path+'core_withLabels.csv','w') 
outfile2=open(dir_path+'core_noLabels.csv','w') 
temp_string=''
for i in files:
    outfile.write(','+i) 
    temp_string=temp_string+i+',' 
temp_string=temp_string[:-1] 
outfile2.write(temp_string+'\n')
outfile.write('\n')
for i in counts: 
    outfile.write(i) 
    temp_string=''
    for j in counts[i]: 
        outfile.write(','+str(j))
        temp_string=temp_string+str(j)+','
   temp_string=temp_string[:-1]
   outfile2.write(temp_string+'\n')
   outfile.write('\n')
outfile.close()
outfile2.close()
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail on what you have and what you've tried?  For example, are the columns known ahead of time or is the number/name of columns determined by the contents of the file?

Comment: Overall I have ~1000 files with 1-100 readnames in them. I know all the potential readnames, but I do not know which ones are in any given file. I would like the code to iterate all the files and tells me which readnames are present/absent in a given file. Let me update the main post with what I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

By matrices, do you mean a numpy matrix or List[List[int]]?

If you know the total number of readnames, numpy matrix is an easy go. For numpy matrix, create a zero matrix of the corresponding size. 
`matrix = np.zeros((n_filenames, n_readnames), dtype=int)`
Alternatively, define 
`matrix = [[] for _ in range(n_filenames)]`

Also, define the map that maps readname to idx in the matrix

```
mapping = dict()
next_available_idx = 0
```

Then, iterate over all files, and fill out the corresponding entries with ones.

```
for i, filename in enumerate(filenames):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for readname in f:
            readname.strip() # get rid of extra spaces
            # find the corresponding column
            if readname in mapping:
                col_idx = mapping[readname]
            else:
                col_idx = next_available_idx
                next_available_idx += 1
                mapping[readname] = col_idx
            matrix[i, col_idx] = 1 # for numpy matrix
            """
            if you use list of lists, then:
            matrix[i] += [0] * (col_idx - len(matrix[i]) + [1]
            """
```

Finally, if you use list of lists, please make sure that the length of all lists is the same. You need to iterate over the rows of matrix one more time.